# How to plot arccotangent function using pgfplots?

Tags: tikz-pgf

Just trying to plot the arccotangent function in tikz/pgfplots, no problem with asin, acos, atan, but at "acot" hit a brick wall. Basic syntax used (just as an example):

```
\draw[color=Maroon,line width=1.75pt,domain=-6.60:6.60] plot[smooth]({\x},{rad(atan(\x))});
```

But it does not work with acot, any suggestions? I am a beginner with tikz/pgfplots, please just basic stuff...

Comment: Try rad(90-atan(\x))

Comment: @JohnKormylo Care for an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cotangent = tangent of the compliment

```
\draw[color=Maroon,line width=1.75pt,domain=-6.60:6.60] plot[smooth]({\x},{rad(90-atan(\x))});
```